# Cassandra slow performance on AWS

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, cassandra

One of our DBAs has benchmarked Cassandra to Oracle on AWS EC2 for INSERT performance (1M records) using the same Python code (below), and got the following surprising results:

**Oracle 12.2**, Single node, 64cores/256GB, EC2 EBS storage, **38 sec**

**Cassandra 5.1.13 (DDAC), Single node**, 2cores/4GB, EC2 EBS storage,  **464 sec**

**Cassandra 3.11.4, Four nodes**, 16cores/64GB(each node), EC2 EBS Storage, **486 sec**

SO - **What are we doing wrong?**
How come Cassandra is performing so slow?
* Not enough nodes? (How come the 4 nodes is slower than single node?)
* Configuration issues?
* Something else?

Thanks!

Following is the Python code:

```
import logging
import time
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, BatchStatement
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

class PythonCassandraExample:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cluster = None
        self.session = None
        self.keyspace = None
        self.log = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.cluster.shutdown()

    def createsession(self):
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='cassandra', password='cassandra')
        self.cluster = Cluster(['10.220.151.138'],auth_provider = auth_provider)
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(self.keyspace)

    def getsession(self):
        return self.session

    # How about Adding some log info to see what went wrong
    def setlogger(self):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.setLevel('INFO')
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"))
        log.addHandler(handler)
        self.log = log

    # Create Keyspace based on Given Name
    def createkeyspace(self, keyspace):
        """
        :param keyspace:  The Name of Keyspace to be created
        :return:
        """
        # Before we create new lets check if exiting keyspace; we will drop that and create new
        rows = self.session.execute("SELECT keyspace_name FROM system_schema.keyspaces")
        if keyspace in [row[0] for row in rows]:
            self.log.info("dropping existing keyspace...")
            self.session.execute("DROP KEYSPACE " + keyspace)

        self.log.info("creating keyspace...")
        self.session.execute("""
                CREATE KEYSPACE %s
                WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2' }
                """ % keyspace)

        self.log.info("setting keyspace...")
        self.session.set_keyspace(keyspace)

    def create_table(self):
        c_sql = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
                                              ename varchar,
                                              sal double,
                                              city varchar);
                 """
        self.session.execute(c_sql)
        self.log.info("Employee Table Created !!!")

    # lets do some batch insert
    def insert_data(self):
        i = 1
        while i < 1000000:
          insert_sql = self.session.prepare("INSERT INTO  employee (emp_id, ename , sal,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
          batch = BatchStatement()
          batch.add(insert_sql, (i, 'Danny', 2555, 'De-vito'))
          self.session.execute(batch)
          # self.log.info('Batch Insert Completed for ' + str(i))
          i += 1

    # def select_data(self):
    #    rows = self.session.execute('select count(*) from perftest.employee limit 5;')
    #    for row in rows:
    #        print(row.ename, row.sal)

    def update_data(self):
        pass

    def delete_data(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example1 = PythonCassandraExample()
    example1.createsession()
    example1.setlogger()
    example1.createkeyspace('perftest')
    example1.create_table()

    # Populate perftest.employee table
    start = time.time()
    example1.insert_data()
    end = time.time()
    print ('Duration: ' + str(end-start) + ' sec.')

    # example1.select_data()
```

Comment: For this kind of benchmarking you should use the same hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We currently have to work with existing hardware. Question is, how come Cassandra, which should be a NoSQL database optimized specifically for quick random inserts and gets, is performing so slow in such an insert load...

Comment: This looks like the DBA is creating an unfair benchmark, perhaps in an attempt to keep the company from moving away from Oracle. While you could work to make a benchmark that highlights the benefits of Cassandra, you're unlikely to match simple insert speed: relational databases are highly tuned for that use case. Moreover, Cassandra doesn't necessarily perform better than alternatives at small scale (and 4 nodes is small: if you look at the Cassandra page, they highlight installations with thousands of nodes).

Comment: 1. What test would you recommend to test Cassandra properly?

2. As far as I know, Cassandra is indeed optimized for single inserts arriving at high velocity... Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I can't recommend a benchmark, because I don't know your workload. And that is by far the most important consideration when developing (or critiquing) a benchmark. If your actual application is writing behaves the same way as your DBA's benchmark, then you would probably be better off with a traditional RDMS.

Comment: Re Cassandra's use case: I have very limited experience (a prototype for one project several years ago), but I would say that it is optimized for a high volume of _concurrent_ operations, against a large distributed dataset. Which is one of the areas that traditional RDMS's aren't very good at, so maybe you should write a competing "benchmark" that uses 100 threads writing to the database.

Comment: Lastly, Cassandra offers a "transparent high-availability" story that traditional RDBMS's don't, which may trump any raw performance concerns. But again, that's dependent on your actual workload (which you haven't described).

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple issues here:

- for 2nd test you didn't allocate enough memory and cores for DDAC, so Cassandra got only 1Gb heap - Cassandra by default takes 1/4th of all available memory. The same is for 3rd test - it will get only 16Gb RAM for heap, you may need to bump it to higher value, like, 24Gb or even higher.
- it's not clear how many IOPs you have in each test - EBS has different throughput depending on the size of the volume, and its type
- You're using synchronous API to execute commands - basically you insert next item after you get confirmation that previous is inserted. The best throughput could be achieved by [using asynchronous API](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#asynchronous-queries);
- You're preparing your statement in every iteration - this lead to sending CQL string to server each time, so it's slows down everything - just move line `insert_sql = self.session.prepare(` out of the loop;
- (not completely related) You're using batch statements to write data - it's [anti-pattern in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html), as data is sent only to one node, that then should distribute data to nodes that really own the data. This explains why 4 nodes cluster is worse than 1 node cluster.

P.S. realistic load testing is quite hard. There are specialized tools for this, you can find, for example, more information in [this blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/02/08/Modeling-real-life-workloads-with-cassandra-stress.html).

Answer (score 0):

The updated code below will batch every 100 records:

```
"""
Python  by Techfossguru
Copyright (C) 2017  Satish Prasad

"""
import logging
import warnings
import time
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, BatchStatement
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

class PythonCassandraExample:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cluster = None
        self.session = None
        self.keyspace = None
        self.log = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.cluster.shutdown()

    def createsession(self):
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='cassandra', password='cassandra')
        self.cluster = Cluster(['10.220.151.138'],auth_provider = auth_provider)
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(self.keyspace)

    def getsession(self):
        return self.session

    # How about Adding some log info to see what went wrong
    def setlogger(self):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.setLevel('INFO')
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"))
        log.addHandler(handler)
        self.log = log

    # Create Keyspace based on Given Name
    def createkeyspace(self, keyspace):
        """
        :param keyspace:  The Name of Keyspace to be created
        :return:
        """
        # Before we create new lets check if exiting keyspace; we will drop that and create new
        rows = self.session.execute("SELECT keyspace_name FROM system_schema.keyspaces")
        if keyspace in [row[0] for row in rows]:
            self.log.info("dropping existing keyspace...")
            self.session.execute("DROP KEYSPACE " + keyspace)

        self.log.info("creating keyspace...")
        self.session.execute("""
                CREATE KEYSPACE %s
                WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2' }
                """ % keyspace)

        self.log.info("setting keyspace...")
        self.session.set_keyspace(keyspace)

    def create_table(self):
        c_sql = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
                                              ename varchar,
                                              sal double,
                                              city varchar);
                 """
        self.session.execute(c_sql)
        self.log.info("Employee Table Created !!!")

    # lets do some batch insert
    def insert_data(self):
        i = 1
        insert_sql = self.session.prepare("INSERT INTO  employee (emp_id, ename , sal,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
        batch = BatchStatement()
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

        while i < 1000001:
          # insert_sql = self.session.prepare("INSERT INTO  employee (emp_id, ename , sal,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
          # batch = BatchStatement()
          batch.add(insert_sql, (i, 'Danny', 2555, 'De-vito'))

          # Commit every 100 records
          if (i % 100 == 0):
             self.session.execute(batch)
             batch = BatchStatement()
             # self.log.info('Batch Insert Completed for ' + str(i))
          i += 1
        self.session.execute(batch)

    # def select_data(self):
    #    rows = self.session.execute('select count(*) from actimize.employee limit 5;')
    #    for row in rows:
    #        print(row.ename, row.sal)

    def update_data(self):
        pass

    def delete_data(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example1 = PythonCassandraExample()
    example1.createsession()
    example1.setlogger()
    example1.createkeyspace('actimize')
    example1.create_table()

    # Populate actimize.employee table
    start = time.time()
    example1.insert_data()
    end = time.time()
    print ('Duration: ' + str(end-start) + ' sec.')

    # example1.select_data()
```

Comment: Don't use batch statements for inserting the data into different partitions! that's bad approach in Cassandra: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html